# Angular - including CSS file in index.html

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use the `angular2-busy` library in an angular project created with the CLI, but am having an issue importing the stylesheet:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css">`

The browser is telling me that it cannot find the file, even with the correct path. I also checked that the file exists, and it does. When I take out the `rel="stylesheet"` I don't get the error, but then the animations don't work.

[image]

Here is the package I am trying to use, if anyone is curious:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy

Comment: Try using a single `./` so `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css">`

Comment: Did not work. I suspect this has something to do with `Angular` as I'm not sure how they handle global CSS files like this.

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: @12seconds Yes, with Angular 4.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Angular CLI have it's own way to initialize your global css/js.

They are located in `.angular-cli.json` configuration

Locate `"styles":` and add your css there

Example :

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css",
   "styles.css"
],
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm still not getting any sort of animation for some reason, but I'm not sure if that's because it's not getting the CSS file.

Comment: @ecain I'm not familiar with the plugin, however just did a quick search on it. It seems like it requires `<div [ngBusy]="busy"></div>` on your template. Do you have that? Also requires you to import it to your AppModule.

Comment: Yes, and it is working, but it simply pops up a string. It is still acting the same as when I had no link to the CSS file at all. So to me that implies it's not "reading" the file.

Comment: @ecain Can you use the browsers dev tools to figure that out? You can do it 2 ways, either inspect the element and see if the <link /> is there. Or check your network tab to see if the style as been loaded.

Comment: Looking at the network tab the style has NOT been loaded. I'm also noticing that it is not even loading the default `styles.css` file either.

Comment: the styles wont be loaded individually, they are bundled up together (if you use cli)

Comment: That makes sense. So do we expect any CSS file to show on the network tab? The only one I see is the `boostrap.min.css` file.

Comment: In that tab you will only see the ones that you included directly in index.html, all the others should appear in something like styles.xxxx.bundle.css. You should in fact to the same for bootstrap with "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" in my opinion, that way your application doesnt rely on external resources

Comment: So is there a way to see whether the CSS file I added in `.angular-cli.json` is being loaded by cli?

Comment: If you know what the styles are you can inspect that styles.xxx.bundle.css and see if it contains any of the expected classes

Comment: yup, the problem is that the bundle.css file is generated only with ng build, ng serve produces a bundle.js file, but the process is the same as the mentioned above to check if the styles were added

Comment: Well I do see the `bundle.js` file.

Comment: in ionic we map it by styleUrls:[]

Comment: And likewise link your JS in
```"scripts": [],```
This is great.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 21):

Basically there are three different ways to do that :-

1. By adding it to the "styles" array in angular-cli.json file as is shown by @penleychan in his answer.

> ```
> "styles": [
>         "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
>         "styles.css"
>       ]
> ```

2. You can directly import the css file into styles.css file (or any other css file) that is included in "styles" array in angular-cli.json file by adding the @import statement at the top of that file.

> ```
> @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
> ```

3. Include the css file in index.html page by adding a link element.

> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
>   href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
>   />

You can find a more elaborated explanation and a few more alternatives at this [link](http://getgoingit.blogspot.in/2018/02/adding-bootstrap-style-sheets-to.html)

Answer (score 10):

### How to Use Angular with Linked Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)

Always use LINKED CSSS rather than the *compiled and embedded* JavaScript memory version of CSS Google Angular uses. Why? Linked `<link>` external CSS is **superior** in every way to embedded CSS, mainly because linked CSS is cached across thousands of page views, visits, and users online, saving you huge bandwidth values with increased CSS rendering speed in the browser, while implementing simpler, faster CSS management, overall.

HOW TO FIX ANGULAR FOR LINKED CSS

1. In **angular.json** delete all the references to CSS files under "styles". It should look like this now:

   ```
     "styles": [],
   ```
2. **Move your CSS files to the"src" folder inside your project, then add links `<link>` to your external CSS files inside index.html**. Add in your link paths to your CSS file starting at the "src" folder and including the "styles" folder or any folder system you desire (see below). You can store your css wherever you want in your project now as long as those folders of files are under your "src" root folder. My physical CSS files in my project for the path below now sit under "src/styles". So the link path should just be my "styles" folder plus the file name:

```
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

3. Any CSS files for **bootstrap**, **font-awesome**, etc. that you want in your project have to be manually copied from your "node_modules" folder in your project into a folder under your "src" folder, just like in the location used for the CSS file above in #2. Or, you can reference them from some *fully qualified url* online. If you want to create a link to them as above in "index.html", or import them into the html file directly (example below), that will also work. If you were importing them before from the "node_modules" folder that will not work as the Angular CLI or webpack resolved those paths by *compiling your CSS imports into JavaScript*. After you move those CSS files and link or import them from the src folder, they will not be compiled into Angular JavaScript now. When using `@import`, be sure to drop your bootstrap and font-awesome CSS files in the same "src/styles" folder as your main style sheet and import them into that stylesheet like this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "bootstrap.min.css";
        @import "font-awesome.min.css";
    </style>
```

4. In the same **angular.json** file above, under the "assets" JSON setting, add a reference to the location of your CSS files in #2 and #3 so the builder can copy them into your dist folder. Any CSS files linked or imported from that folder will get moved by the "dist" folder system when Angular is compiled. Note the new styles path at the bottom. If you have CSS in other folders you can add them here as well. This tells the builder to create the CSS directories in the "dist" folder Angular uses and copy all the CSS files inside them, so when you build for production your index.html links point to the right CSS files on the server:

   ```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      "src/api",
      "src/styles"
    ],
   ```

You now have a powerful set of link elements to all your CSS in the head of your index.html file and can edit them in the Angular project like you normally do, knowing they will work in both the Angular development test server and in your dist production copy. Your website will also benefit from browser caching of CSS one time in memory and permanent file caches.

It took me a day to dig through documentation and testing to figure out what **should** have been a natural part of any *simple website API* with linked CSS. I'm sorry Google Angular made this so *convoluted*. But this change works great!

This simply removes your CSS from the compile and build angular system that pushes all your CSS into a JavaScript file, which simply embedded your CSS into an inline style sheet block in the memory of your browser and head of your HTML page. Using your own linked CSS html tags is far superior and allows better caching and control of CSS cascade rules.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css" >
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I should add that I am also using `Bootstrap` and am having no issues importing their CSS file from a CDN.

Comment: where is your index file?based on that you need to adjust the path

Comment: Index is 1 folder in away from the `node_modules` folder. I tried using `..` to go up a folder, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the self closing / at the end of your code. It's possible the browser is not fixing this for you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css" />
```

Also removing  rel="stylesheet" would definitely not fix the problem since the browser needs to know exactly what kind reference you are referring to.

If fixing the closing tag does not work then your path is wrong. You can also try adding a ../ to the beginning of your path. This will make it relative to the folder the site is in.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css" />
```

Comment: You don't need a `/` at the end of a link.

Comment: @ecain You do if you are trying to make your code compatible with older browsers which would fail to compile that line. And its not at the end of the link its at the end of the html line. It is a self closing tag /, not a closing / for a hyperlink reference.

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately, that hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: @ecain can you post up your directory structure? that might help us figure out why your link is not working. Try doing this. Take the file and add it to your root WWW folder and then just reference it using its name  "busy.css"