# How to properly include CSS/JS in an Angular distribution

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement an Admin Template I used in my classic PHP application in a new Angular project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/plugins/images/favicon.png">
    <title>Ample Admin Template - The Ultimate Multipurpose admin template</title>
    <link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/plugins/bower_components/sidebar-nav/dist/sidebar-nav.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/colors/blue-dark.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">      
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The application is properly rendered by now I have some questions:

1. How can I include these CSS/JS package (and all the dependencies) in an Angular distribution?
2. What is the proper way to includes external CSS/libraries in Angular?

Comment: take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224032/angular-including-css-file-in-index-html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Top-Level Styles

If the styling items you have shown in the `<head>` tag are meant to be top-level styles (as opposed to component styles: [Angular Components Styling](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)), add the file references in your `angular-cli.json` file under the "styles" property.

This SO answer has an example: [Angular - including CSS file in index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224032/angular-including-css-file-in-index-html).

You can place as many files into the "styles" array as you would like -- these will be added to a styling bundle when Webpack runs on your application's initialization, which will then be placed in the index.html's `<head>` tag.

### Webpack

If you need some information on how Webpack is used in Angular or how to configure it, the Angular Documentation site has a [solid explanation](https://angular.io/guide/webpack).

### External CSS Libraries

For "external CSS/libraries" you may use the `styleUrls` property in your Components. You can review the Component Styles Angular Documentation information [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#loading-component-styles).