# How to include .css file of my component in angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, angular-components, angular-module

I have included my component's .css file in this manner
`

```
angular.
  module('home').
  component('home', {
    templateUrl: 'home/home.template.html',
    styleUrls: 'home/home.component.css'
    
    
  });
```

`
But it seems that the stylesheet is not getting applied.
What is the right way of including the stylesheet?
[This is the folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbP4t.png)

Comment: just wondering why you are writing angular 2 in javascript instead of typescript.
Also, the way you have pasted the code makes it look like angular.js, not angular 2+ guidelines

Comment: I have a project to be built in angular 1.x which includes .js files .

Answer (score 0):

styleUrls accepts an array

```
styleUrls: ['home/home.component.css']
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't make a difference. Css isn't getting applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put square brackets on the url like this: `styleUrls: ['home/home.component.css']`

```css
angular.
  module('home').
  component('home', {
    templateUrl: 'home/home.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['home/home.component.css']
    
    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced the same problem and then I found the answer. just add this line inside the component declaration :

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

for example, 

@Component({
  templateUrl: './usertradedata.component.html',
  animations: [appModuleAnimation()],
  styleUrls:['./usertradedata.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this
[click link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224032/angular-including-css-file-in-index-html)

```
"styles": [
"../node_modules/angular2-busy/build/style/busy.css",
"styles.css"
],
```

in .angular-cli.json